# Azure WebRole accepting requests before being ready

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I observe a strange situation and see that a WebRole is accepting requests even when being in  `Busy (Waiting for role to start... Calling OnRoleStart. [2014-03-12T10:59:41Z])` state.

I am intentionally setting `Thread.Sleep(1000*60*3);` in WebRole OnStart() to allow a silent installations, but the requests are getting in despite OnStart being busy.

I have verified that I don't have `ignoreRoleInstanceStatus` set in code.